# Collection in WITH clause gets expanded to one element per row

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want to create a map projection with node properties and some additional information.
Also I want to collect some ids in a collection and use this later in the query to filter out nodes (where ID(n) in ids...).
The map projection is created in an apoc call which includes several union matches.

```
call apoc.cypher.run('MATCH (n)-[:IS_A]->({name: "User"}) MATCH (add)-[:IS_A]->({name: "AdditionalInformationForUser"}) RETURN n{.*, info: collect(add.name), id: ID(n)} as nodeWithInfo UNION MATCH (n)-[:IS_A]->({Department}) MATCH (add)-[:IS_A]->({"AdditionalInformationForDepartment"}) RETURN n{.*, info: collect(add.name), id: ID(n)} as nodeWithInfo', NULL) YIELD value
WITH (value.nodeWithInfo) AS nodeWithInfo
WITH collect(nodeWithInfo.id) as nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds, nodeWithInfo
MATCH (n)-[:has]->({"Vacation"})
MATCH (u)-[:is]->({"Out of Order"})
WHERE ID(n) in nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds and ID(u) in nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds
return n, u, nodeWithInfo
```

This does not return anything because, when the where part is evaluated it doesn´t check "nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds" as a flat list but instead only gets one id per row.
The problem only exists because I am passing the ids (nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds) AND the nodeProjection (nodeWithInfo) on in the WITH clause.

If I instead only use the id collection and don´t use the nodeWithInfo projection the following adjustement works and returns my only the nodes which ids are in the id collection:

```
...
WITH collect(nodeWithInfo.id) as nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds
    MATCH (n)-[:has]->({"Urlaub"})
    MATCH (u)-[:is]->({"Out of Order"})
    WHERE ID(n) in nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds and ID(u) in nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds
    return n, u
```

If I just return the collection "nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds" directly after the WITH clause in both examples this gets obvious. Since the first one generates a flat list in one result row and the second one gives me one id per row.

I have the feeling that I am missing a crucial knowledge about neo4js With clause.
Is there a way I can pass on my listOfIds and use it as a flat list without the need to have an exclusive WITH clause for the collection?

edit:
Right now I am using the following workaround:
After I do the check on the ID of "n" and "u" I don´t return but instead keep the filtered "n" and "u" nodes and start a second apoc call that returns "nodeWithInfo" like before.

```
WITH n, u
call apoc.cypher.run('MATCH (n)-[:IS_A]->({name: "User"}) MATCH (add)-[:IS_A]->({name: "AdditionalInformationForUser"}) RETURN n{.*, info: collect(add.name), id: ID(n)} as nodeWithInfo UNION MATCH (n)-[:IS_A]->({Department}) MATCH (add)-[:IS_A]->({"AdditionalInformationForDepartment"}) RETURN n{.*, info: collect(add.name), id: ID(n)} as nodeWithInfo', NULL) YIELD value
WITH (value.nodeWithInfo) AS nodeWithInfo, n, u
WHERE nodeWithInfo.id = ID(n) OR nodeWithInfo.id = ID(u)
RETURN nodeWithInfo, n, u
```

This way I can return the nodes n, u and the additional information (to one of the nodes) per row. But I am sure there must be a better way.

I know ids in neo4j have to be used with care, if at all. In this case I only need them to be valid inside this query, so it doesn´t matter if the next time the same node has another id.

The problem is stripped down to the core problem (in my opinion), the original query is a little bigger with several UNION MATCH inside apoc and the actual match on nodes which ids are contained in my collection is checking for some more restrictions instead of asking for any node.

Answer (score 1):

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/#query-functions-aggregating), like `COLLECT()`, aggregate over *a set of "grouping keys"*.

- In the following clause:

  ```
   WITH collect(nodeWithInfo.id) as nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds, nodeWithInfo
  ```

  the grouping key is `nodeWithInfo`. Therefore, each `nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds` would always be a list containing one value.
- And in the following clause:

  ```
  WITH collect(nodeWithInfo.id) as nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds
  ```

  there is no grouping key. Therefore, in this situation, `nodesWithAdditionalInfosIds` will contain all the `nodeWithInfo.id` values.